# How can I send hyperlink in discord.js

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, discord.js

how to make something like

> [CLICK HERE](https://goog.com)

on `message.channel.send()` and when click, you will get redirected to link or message link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an [`embed`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview) and set your `message` as the title. Afterwards, you can set the `URL` so that the `title` becomes a `hyperlink`

Example:

```js
message.channel.send({
   embed: {
      title: 'Your message',
      url: 'Some URL',
   },
});
```